# Wordpress search template for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I made a custom post type plugin to display team member in wordpress name team to display custom post type I made `archive-team.php` and `single-team.php` all that works great and independent  of theme used.

Now my problem is that I want to include custom post type in search also but I think there is no such thing `searh-team.php` and to display search template for custom post type i have to modify `search.php` which varies from theme to theme.

So can anyone point me in right direction to make search template independent of theme.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Follow these 3 steps to achieve custom post search.

Lets say your custom post type name is employee_member.

1. Add Below code into function.php

   ```
   function template_chooser($template)   
   {    
     global $wp_query;   
     $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');   
     if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'employee_member' )   
     {
       return locate_template('employee-search.php');  //  redirect to archive-search.php
     }   
     return $template;   
   }
   add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
   ```
2. Create file employee-search.php

---

```
/* Template Name: Custom Search */
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="contentarea">
    <div id="content" class="content_right">
        <h3>Search Result for : <?php echo "$s"; ?> </h3>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="posts">
            <article>
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <p><?php the_exerpt(); ?></p>
                <p align="right"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read     More</a></p>
                <span class="post-meta"> Post By <?php the_author(); ?>
                    | Date : <?php echo date('j F Y'); ?>
                </span>

            </article><!-- #post -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- contentarea -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

3. Finally create a search form for your custom post type

---

```
<div>   
   <h3>Search Employee Member</h3>
   <form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">
       <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Products"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="employee_member" /> 
       <input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you edit your answer please.your code seems to be broken here.

Answer (score 0):

## Use pre_get_posts() to alter the query

To do this, a good practice is to use pre_get_posts() to alter the search query.
This code can be dropped in the functions.php of the theme or directly into a plugin.

```
<?php
// Call our function my_search()
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search' );

function my_search($query) {

    // Check if we are on the front end main search query
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {

        // Change the post_type parameter on the query
        $query->set('post_type', 'team');
    }

    // Return the modified query
    return $query;
}
?>
```

The search will now be queried only your custom post type "team".
If you would like the research also integrates post and pages, you can modify the following line:

```
<?php
$query->('post_type', array('team', 'post', 'page'));
?>
```

If you use the add_filter() in a PHP Class, be careful to declare your filter like this:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'my_search' ) );
?>
```

Comment: actually say  search result my custom post type and regular post.so i wanted to display regular post as it is while custom post type to different way.hope that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your `functions.php` :

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'team')); // Add all post types you want results for.
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```